# OpenAPI and @Schema annotation on Java Enum

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, microprofile, thorntail

I’m generating OpenAPI 3.0 documentation from annotated java code. But the issue is that when I add @Schema annotation to enum all the values disappear. I'm using Thorntail 2.3.0.Final with microprofile-openapi fraction.

I know I can just change the .yaml file but I need my yaml to be generated directly from Java code.

Here is my minimal example on github:
https://github.com/pkristja/openApiEnumSchema

Source code for enum:

```
package com.example.openapiexample.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;

@Schema(description = "<div class=\\\"renderedMarkdown\\\"><p>Rank of developer.</p>\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<p>Valid values are:</p>\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<ul>\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<li>'JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_1': Text for junior 1.\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<li>'JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_2': Text for junior 2.\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<li>'JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_3': Text for junior 3.\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<li>'SENIOR_DEVELOPER_1': Text for senior 1.\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<li>'SENIOR_DEVELOPER_2': Text for senior 1.\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<li>'SENIOR_DEVELOPER_3': Text for senior 1.\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"</ul>\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"<p>Random text...\\n\" +\n" +
        "        \"and has to be added to this API definition as well.</p></div>",
        enumeration = {"junior_developer_1", "junior_developer_2", "junior_developer_3",
                "senior_developer_1", "senior_developer_2", "senior_developer_3"})
public enum Rank {
    JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_1("junior_developer_1"),
    JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_2("junior_developer_2"),
    JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_3("junior_developer_3"),
    SENIOR_DEVELOPER_1("senior_developer_1"),
    SENIOR_DEVELOPER_2("senior_developer_2"),
    SENIOR_DEVELOPER_3("senior_developer_3");

    private String value;

    Rank(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Rank fromValue(String text) {
        for (Rank b : Rank.values()) {
            if (String.valueOf(b.value).equals(text)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And source code for Object including enum:

```
package com.example.openapiexample.model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;

@Data
@Schema(description = "Schema for Developer object...")
public class Developer {

    @Schema(required = true, description = "First name of the developer")
    private String firstName;
    @Schema(required = true, description = "Last name of the developer")
    private String lastName;
    @Schema(required = true, implementation = Rank.class)
    private Rank developerRank;
}
```

Snipped of generated OpenAPI 3.0 documentation:

```
 schemas:
    Developer:
      description: Schema for Developer object...
      required:
      - developerRank
      - firstName
      - lastName
      properties:
        developerRank:
          description: |-
            <div class=\"renderedMarkdown\"><p>Rank of developer.</p>\n" +
                    "<p>Valid values are:</p>\n" +
                    "<ul>\n" +
                    "<li>'JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_1': Text for junior 1.\n" +
                    "<li>'JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_2': Text for junior 2.\n" +
                    "<li>'JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_3': Text for junior 3.\n" +
                    "<li>'SENIOR_DEVELOPER_1': Text for senior 1.\n" +
                    "<li>'SENIOR_DEVELOPER_2': Text for senior 2.\n" +
                    "<li>'SENIOR_DEVELOPER_3': Text for senior 3.\n" +
                    "</ul>\n" +
                    "<p>Random text...\n" +
                    "and has to be added to this API definition as well.</p></div>
          type: string
          properties:
            value:
              type: string
        firstName:
          description: First name of the developer
          type: string
        lastName:
          description: Last name of the developer
          type: string
```

But if I remove @Schema annotation before enum in Developer class I get generated enum values but without description and required value like this:

```
schemas:
    Developer:
      description: Schema for Developer object...
      required:
      - firstName
      - lastName
      properties:
        developerRank:
          enum:
          - JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_1
          - JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_2
          - JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_3
          - SENIOR_DEVELOPER_1
          - SENIOR_DEVELOPER_2
          - SENIOR_DEVELOPER_3
          type: string
        firstName:
          description: First name of the developer
          type: string
        lastName:
          description: Last name of the developer
          type: string
```

Is there a way I can have have both enum values and description or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi, is there any working solution for this issue? I would like to use a different enum attribute than the name as allowed value as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @Schema for the enum to indicate it to use the value property instead of the name property by specifying the implementation class.

For example

```
@Schema(implementation = Rank::class)
public enum Rank {
    JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_1("junior_developer_1"),
    JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_2("junior_developer_2"),
    JUNIOR_DEVELOPER_3("junior_developer_3"),
    SENIOR_DEVELOPER_1("senior_developer_1"),
    SENIOR_DEVELOPER_2("senior_developer_2"),
    SENIOR_DEVELOPER_3("senior_developer_3");

    private String value;

    Rank(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    :
}
```

Comment: How does this use the `value` property instead of the `name` property? I even tried it in the compiler (after fixing your `::` typo and it does not work as promised.

Comment: Can you provide a fixed example please? I need a solution as well.